# Чтения PDF версии 1.5 PHP

Tags: php, pdf

Есть следующий php код:

```
<?php
$file = 'somefile.pdf';
ob_clean();
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . basename($file) . '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');;
readfile($file);
```

При попытке прочитать им PDF файл, в браузере вываливается ошибка "не удалось загрузить PDF-документ".
После долгих разбирательств, я пришел к тому, что php не может адекватно прочитать этот PDF файл таким образом, так как он версии 1.5. Есть ли способ адекватно прочитать через php подобный PDF используя только php, либо какой-то БЕСПЛАТНЫЙ парсер?

Comment: зачем здесь ob_clean()?

Answer (score -1):

Проблема решена понижением версии пхп с 7.4 до 5.3. Всё замечательно читает и рисует в браузере.